# Origen e historia de la palabra "pálpito"

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos

Mi mujer, como buena gaditana, tiene un rico vocabulario de palabras y expresiones propias de la región. El otro día surgió en una conversación la palabra *pálpito*, registrada en el DLE así:

> **[pálpito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RbMtQuf)**
>
> De *palpitar*.
>
> 1. m. Presentimiento, corazonada.

Esta palabra está registrada en el DLE desde 1970 (y entonces en un suplemento). Sintiendo curiosidad por el origen de la palabra, leo en algunas fichas del *Fichero general* de la RAE que en España se usa en Cádiz y Jaén (puede que esto ya no sea así, la ficha es de los años 70), mientras que en Hispanoamérica parece de uso general, oyéndose en Argentina, Bolivia, Chile, Perú, México, Puerto Rico y Uruguay (y no sé si algún otro país).

Algunos determinan el origen de esta palabra en el portugués *[palpite](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/palpite)* ("conocimiento intuitivo", por influencia brasileña), que de hecho es [como se dice](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=palpite) (aunque poco) en Uruguay, y también daría lugar al *[pálpite](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=p%C3%A1lpite)* de Paraguay. Sin embargo, su uso en México despista bastante y no hay certeza pues de que esto sea así.

Ya buscando textos concretos, el caso más antiguo que consigo encontrar es de la revista *Caras y Caretas*, de Argentina, de 1900:

> *Dijose que el afortunado mortal, millonario de golpe, había soñado con los apostóles y que por eso compró el número que suma 12. Añadióse que un «palpito» fué el que le movió á hacer la compra.*
>
> Caras y caretas (Buenos Aires). 29/12/1900, n.º 117, página 33.

Ahora mismo el pálpito que tengo es que la palabra sí que pudo venir del portugués, comenzó como *palpite* y *pálpite* en Uruguay y Paraguay, situados entre Brasil y Argentina, y a Argentina llegó como *pálpito*, y de ahí se extendería por Chile y Perú hacia el norte. Sin embargo, no consigo encontrar casos de *palpite* antes de 1900 que confirmen esta evolución, aunque en la versión uruguaya de *Caras y Caretas*, de 1890, hay algunos artículos firmados por "Palpite", que no sé si tendrá algo que ver (suena a seudónimo). <strike>Tampoco sé cuán antigua es la palabra en el portugués ([he preguntado al respecto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5454/4296) en el sitio de portugués), necesitaría ser de uso en Brasil en el siglo XIX.</strike> La palabra desde luego sí se usaba en Brasil en el siglo XIX, como atestigua la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5454/4296) en el sitio sobre el portugués (y la [respuesta de pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27188/12637)). Por último, tampoco sé cómo ni cuándo llegó a España, ni por qué se usaba aquí de forma tan localizada, al menos hacia mediados del siglo XX.

¿Alguien me ayuda a completar el rompecabezas del origen e historia de la palabra *pálpito*?

Comment: Veo en Meta Portuguese.SE que también hay un Corpus: https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/168/931. Mirando en él (https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) veo alguna referencia, pero no queda claro si su uso es el mismo.

Comment: en Mexico para un presentimiento decimos "Se me hace que", es esto usado también en otros paises ?

Answer (score 2):

Viendo el corpus de portugués mencionado en los comentarios, observo que *palpite* aparece varias veces con su valor de "corazonada" o "intuición repentina" o quizá "impulso" en obras del último cuarto del s. XIX, por ejemplo:

- José de Alencar, *Senhora* (1875): *«Não são negócios que se resolvem assim de palpite.»*
- Raúl Pompéia, *As joias de Coroa* (1882): *«Queria ver que valor tinha um palpite que lhe viera à toa.»*
- Aluízio Azevedo, *Casa de pensão* (1890): *«Acredita, Loló, que desde a chegada do Amâncio, tive cá um palpite de que aquela mulher seria um estorvo para os nossos projetos!»*

También aparece varias veces la palabra, en esa misma época, en el corpus de al menos dos escritores portugueses, lo cual indica que al menos esta acepción era conocida en Portugal:

- Jílio Dínis, *Os fidalgos da casa mourisca* (1871): *«A baronesa adivinhou logo que era Berta e aplaudiu-se do palpite que a fizera desviar do caminho para subir ali.»*
- Eça de Queirós, *O primo Basílio* (1882): «Mas um terror importuno tolhia-a; sentia como um palpite de que ele vinha, ia entrar...»

De manera que *palpite* existía con valor de "corazonada" o "impulso" ya en Portugal y Brasil en las últimas tres décadas del siglo XIX, y probablemente antes, ya que si una nueva acepción de una palabra aparece en el registro literario en un determinado momento es porque ya existía con anterioridad en el habla.

Lo extraño del caso es cómo de *palpite* se pasa a *pálpito*, con un cambio de acentuación, salvo que *pálpito* ya fuese palabra corriente en castellano en ese momento con el significado que hoy reservamos para *palpitación*.

Comment: Sorry for writing in English. Coming from the Portuguese site, my first thought was also why would the main stress shift from the second to the first syllable. But your suggestion makes sense. It could be just a “semantic Portuguesism”: Spanish speakers would get the logic of Portuguese *palpite* ―which is fairly transparent―and adapt to *pálpito*.

Comment: In Google Books you find examples of *palpite* used from 1848.

Comment: @Jacinto Obrigadíssimo!